# Does the 90-day passport rule count for Austria if I have a Spanish NIE?

Tags: schengen, passports, paperwork, us-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

How likely is it that I will be able to board a plane from Spain to Austria with a passport that expires in less than 90 days, if I have a valid long-term residency card (NIE) for Spain (which shows that I am legally tied to the Schengen countries)?

I am booked on a flight to Austria in 10 days, and I don't think I can get a new passport that fast.

Answer (score 3):

The three-month rule applies to those who are *entering* the Schengen zone.  Therefore, it does not apply to you for this trip.

The three-month rule is imposed by the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) at Article 6(1)(a)(i), which is part of Chapter 1, *Crossing of external borders and conditions for entry.*  (I say "three months" rather than "90 days" because that is what the code says: *"...its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended date of departure..."*).

You are not crossing an external border, so you are not entering the Schengen zone, and this article does not apply to you.  You should therefore have no trouble boarding the flight.

Comment: TIMATIC isn't programmed to reflect this fact though, so no matter how correct, it probably can't be used as an argument to permit Boarding (wheras the info in my answer definitely can). Also the 3-month doesn't apply if you have a residence Permit, even if entering Schengen

Comment: @Coke "the 3-month [rule] doesn't apply if you have a residence Permit, even if entering Schengen": do you have a reference for that?  The Schengen Borders Code says that the three month rule can (must, in fact) be applied if the person is entering Schengen for a purpose other than transit to the country that issued the residence card. So if Sonia were trying to pop into Austria in the middle of a vacation in Serbia, she should be refused entry. Will this ever actually happen to anyone? I highly doubt it; it's a nonsensical result. But that's what it says.

Comment: Possibly, but TIMATIC publishes actual practice at the border (as opposed to formal law, whenever there is a difference, which my IATA contact has stated isn't uncommon at all), and it's what check-in goes by. They're **not** going to browse the Schengen Borders Code

Comment: @Coke It might be actual practice at the airport of departure unfortunately but what basis do you have to claim it's the practice *at the border*? Border guards are more likely to refer to the Schengen Borders code than to some random IATA database.

Comment: @phoog Article 6(5)(a) does give some room for exceptions to the three-month rule for residence permit holders.

Comment: @Relaxed that's what I meant to invoke when I said "for a purpose other than transit," which as far as I can see is the only exception provided by 6(5)(a).

Comment: @Relaxed However, TIMATIC is based on information from border authorities, so the info isn't simply made up from IATA's rear ends. In Addition, OP asked about Boarding the flight, for which TIMATIC is the determining factor.

Comment: @phoog "but what basis do you have to claim it's the practice at the border?" My IATA contact (the sourcing Manager) has been very clear in telling me that TIMATIC is about *de facto* regulations as enforced at the border, which they're informed about by the relevant border authorities.

Comment: @Coke That's what I always assumed... but that's not quite the same thing as actual practice at the border, hence my question.

Comment: @Relaxed The difference being? I'd post a link to continue in Chat but don't know how to do that

Comment: @Coke Misinformed border guards for example. Actual practice at the border is what happens at the border, information from the relevant border authorities is someone's interpretation of the law in a ministry office somewhere. Differences between the two are also not uncommon at all.

Comment: @Coke but "actual practice at the border" can vary from country to country, can't it?  The link to continue in chat will appear at some point (probably very soon) after you click the "add a comment" link.

Comment: @Relaxed I admit the sources can be wrong in exceptional cases (I've had to tell off the mainland Danes for supplying wrong information regarding the Faroe Islands on a specific matter, which was corrected when I asked the Faroese Police to notify IATA). However, it is consistently written in TIMATIC, regarding all Schengen states, that passports of residence Permit holders Need only be valid on Arrival. This, combined with the logical factor, gives me no reason to doubt it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by check-in staff:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     residents of Spain must be valid on arrival.

So you only need a valid-on-arrival passport (and residence permit) because you have a Schengen residence permit.

For US citizens without a Schengen residence permit, TIMATIC instead states:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for at a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay

That's the difference

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Both the US passport and my Spanish NIE will be valid throughout my travel (from Spain to Austria and back) but the passport expires 2 months from my date of travel (not 3).

Comment: Is my passport considered "valid" if that is the case? Thanks.

Comment: @Sonia When it says "valid on arrival" it means no period beyond that is needed. It's because you have a Schengen residence permit.